# Having a command input problem in Ubuntu 18.04 WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

EDIT: Most of this has been resolved, but I have **just one final question**.

Where did the packages directory go to?  I don't know how to locate the folder it was put in, even if it says `usr/local/EmojicodePackages`, I don't know where that is.

[image: must locate /usr/local/EmojicodePackages but don't know where it is]
[image: Error trying to install from .sh file on my computer]

It just says 'command not found'.  I don't know if I'm typing the command correctly though.

The command is meant to be:

[image: what the command line looks like]

<sup>(from https://www.emojicode.org/docs/guides/install.html (part of the manual installation of emojicode))</sup>

My version is the version of the software I want, and platform is Linux (I assume, as I'm using Ubuntu WSL).

I don't know how to put `./install.sh` into a new line without executing what I've already typed.  I hit enter, but it executes the command instead of taking me to a new line where I can put in `./install.sh` as seen in the image.  So, how do I go to a new line?

EDIT: I tried inputting the full path to the install file (dragging and dropping in terminal; *full path is not visible in screen cap*), but it says there's too many arguments.  So, I THINK (though I don't know for sure) that it could be because I typed it wrong.  Ie. Maybe it needs to go in another line.  Maybe there's some spaces that go in between.

It could be anything under the sun, but the website I got the command from has no way to contact them to get help on how to input the command properly.  I'm hoping any one of you guys knows what's up, or if you know how to do a new line in the terminal, then you can tell me how to do that.  Either helps.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  Where would I type cd?  Example command?

Comment: So how do I put in a new line?  I'm really noob when it comes to this

Comment: Very weird, it says 'no such file or directory' even though I input it after cd.  I dragged and dropped the folder into bash, and it still can't find it, apparently.  Also, pressing enter executes the command instead of giving a new line.  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 from the windows store

Comment: And the Ubuntu app is on the same drive as the folder I want it to find.  I dragged it into terminal, as you said.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you broaden their scope which makes them harder to answer. On top of that it likely invalidates existing answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on WSL, anything you download on your browser would be stored in the following directory. Dragging and dropping the path from windows will in fact not work as your normal drives are under `/mnt`:

```
/mnt/c/Users/<your-username>/Downloads/
```

and excecuting your above commands should work, however you can download, untar and install Emojicode all at once with the following command sequence:

```
wget https://github.com/emojicode/emojicode/releases/download/v0.5.4/Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz -O emojicode.tar.gz \
&& tar -xzf emojicode.tar.gz && rm emojicode.tar.gz \
&& cd Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64 && ./install.sh \
&& cd .. && rm -r Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64
```

- `wget` downloads the tar file -> saves it as `emojicode.tar.gz`
- `tar` uncompresses `emojicode.tar.gz` -> `Emojicode-0.5.4-Linux-x86_64`
- then we `cd` into the new folder and run `install.sh` to install emojicode
- finally we `cd ..` to go back to the parent directory and use `rm` to remove the folder we've extracted the emojicode source to because we don't need it anymore

Comment: It actually worked that time around, but at the end I still got a message saying '-r: command not found' after it successfully installed.  Thanks very much for your trouble

Comment: Is the username the ubuntu username, or my windows user?

Comment: @nofreewill your windows username.

Answer (score 0):

The 'command' is really two commands - you do need the newline to run them spearately.

The first, 'cd Emojicode-blah...' sets the current directory (cd) to the folder that contains the file install.sh - from your screen shot it doesn't look like that folder is being found.  Is the Emojicode... folder inside your Downloads folder?  Somewhere else?  If it's in Downloads, then type:

```
    cd Downloads/Emojicode-etc...
```

The second command is './install.sh' - this runs a script to install the software.

Comment: It's actually sitting in my desktop.  I dragged it in, and it says no such file or directory.